# CSV files seperated by dot instead of comma. Panda, Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

when I merge three lists into one and then use pandas to create a dataframe and then create a CSV the CSV created has the lists values separated by a dot instead of a comma.

The code :

```
qup = []
for i in range(0,len(year)):
    qup.append(invention[i]+year[i])

df = pd.DataFrame(qup)
df.to_csv("quo.csv")
```

Output:

[The CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMelc.png)

Thanks!

Comment: The problem isn't the comma separator, it's `invention[i]+year[i]`.

Comment: What you posted creates a dataframe with a *single* column whose values are whatever `invention[i]+year[i]` produces. If those are strings, you'll end up with string concatenation.

Comment: If you want to create a dataframe with separate `invention` and `year` columns create a dictionary with the lists eg: `d={'invention':invention,'year':year}` and then create the DataFrame from the dictionary `df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the code, not `to_csv`. The code creates a single column dataframe whose values are the result of the string concatenation expression `invention[i]+year[i]`. The dots are already there, probably at the end of each `invention` value.

To create a DataFrame from column values, start by creating a dictionary of the values using the desired column names as keys:

```
d = {'invention':invention,'year':year}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```